# »mehr ... als …« vs. »mehr … denn …«

Tags: word-usage, difference, comparison

Wir kennen die Phrase *mehr denn je.* Kann die Konjunktion *denn* auch in anderen Zusammenhängen gebraucht werden? Zum Beispiel:

> Mehr Krieg denn Frieden (mehr Krieg als Frieden)

Gibt es in diesem Zusammenhang Unterschiede zur Konjunktion *als?*

---

We know about the phrase *mehr denn je.* Is it possible to use *denn* in other contexts like the following?

> Mehr Krieg denn Frieden (mehr Krieg als Frieden)

Is there a difference between *denn* and *als* in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Verwendung von *als* ist die moderne Form, während *denn* poetisch bis altertümlich klingt. Beide Formen sind aber identisch in ihrer Bedeutung.

Schon damals in Grimms Wörterbuch wurde darauf hingewiesen, besser *als* zu verwenden (siehe 2. von *denn*<sup>[(1)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GD01603#XGD01603)</sup> ):

> *... ebenso findet nach comparativen und comparativischen verneinungen, nach* nichts, nichts anders *jetzt blosz* denn *statt, aber es wird nicht von jedem gebraucht und dafür lieber* als *gesagt; […]*

Comment: Könntest Du eine Refferenz (einen Beleg) angeben?

Comment: Ich habe einen Beleg aus Grimms Wörterbuch hinzugefügt. Der gemeinsame Ursprung könnte "als denn/als dann" gewesen sein.

Answer (score 2):

"denn" in der Bedeutung "als" ist derart veraltet, daß es nur im Idiom "mehr denn je" anstandslos verstanden wird.

Erschwerend kommt hinzu, daß "denn" mehrere andere rezente Bedeutungen hat (Ich lache, denn ich bin froh / Wo bist du denn gewesen?); es ist also nicht einmal sofort als seltenes archaisches Wort kenntlich wie z.B. "derweil". Von der Benutzung ist also grundsätzlich abzuraten.

Answer (score 1):

Ähnlich wie bereits in den anderen Antworten findet man auch in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* die Erklärung, dass *denn* als Vergleichspartikel veraltet ist und fast durchweg durch *als* ersetzt wurde. Es wird nur noch in bestimmten Verbindungen und aus stilistischen Gründen in gehobener Ausdrucksweise verwendet.

> Er benimmt sich mehr wie ein Freund denn wie ein Fremder.
>
> Er ist mir mehr denn je verhasst

Insbesondere wird *denn* gebraucht, um ein doppeltes *als* zu vermeiden:

> Er ist als Forscher bedeutender denn als Schriftsteller.
> *statt:* Er ist als Forscher bedeutender als als Schriftsteller.

Comment: Der letzte Punkt wurde hier noch nicht betrachtet und ist interessant, d.h. immerhin, dass "denn" im Vergleichs-Kontext nach wie vor relevant ist.

Comment: Es gibt genug andere Möglichkeiten, das veraltete "denn" beim doppelten "als" zu vermeiden, d.h. es gibt hier keine Notwendigkeit, es deswegen weiter zu gebrauchen. Doppeltes "als" erachte ich auch nicht als schlimm. Ich z.B. verwende "denn" deswegen trotzdem niemals als Ersatz für "als".